# Why can't I use mpirun installed using conda instead of /usr/bin/mpirun?

Tags: gcc, anaconda, conda, mpi, mpich

I have created a fresh `conda` environment and installed `mpirun`. However, `which mpirun` gives me `/usr/bin/mpirun`. Moreoever, I cannot find `mpirun` in `..../anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/`. Same goes for `mpicxx` or `mpicc`. Although I could see `gcc` and `gxx` in the anaconda bin. What's going on? How can I use the anaconda `mpirun` and others instead of the system packages?

Note that `conda install -c conda-forge mpich` works fine but `conda install -c conda-forge mpich-mpicxx` gets frozen.

Also note that `echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}` shows conda path at the top.

Sorry for asking this basic question but I somehow mess this up while working on a remote cluster.